# Ajaxify product details on collection page {Shopify}

Tags: jquery, ajax, themes, shopify

I'm using Ajaxify on my selfmade shopify theme. It works wonders and I love it. However, designed the .ajaxified-cart-feedback class to show the item that has been added. Like this:

[image]

However, when your adding an item from a collection, it does not display the spesific product information in the box. Anybody know how I can make this happen?

[image]

Another issue is to try and make the .ajaxified-cart-feedback box fade away afer 2000 milliseconds. I see this is a config in for the add to cart input, but not for the after added feedback.

Looking forward to any inputs of feedback.

Comment: Give SweetAlert and JavaScript a try. It's very clean. I'm doing that for my page on multiple locations.

Comment: Ajaxify might not be able to run javascripts inside the response. It's hard to answer your questions, they're very broad. You're best looking at Timber framework. If you want to "ajaxify" a shopify website, you're best using pjax.